HDD hiccups randomly, no SMART errors
I use an SSD as boot drive and an HDD as /home drive.
For about the last 2 weeks, the HDD randomly "hiccups" and the system takes one or two seconds to come back to itself. It does not reboot nor crash. There was a slow and hot case Fan, I thought that might be the issue and disconnected it, but the problem persists. I've also changed the SATA cable and port, but to no avail. I bought the HDD in March.
There is also a beep but I'm not sure if it comes from the motherboard buzzer or the HDD.
The outputs of hdsentinel and smartctl
HDD Device  1: /dev/sdb
HDD Model ID : ST2000DM008-2UB102
HDD Serial No: WK30LBZ6
HDD Revision : 0001
HDD Size     : 1907729 MB
Interface    : S-ATA Gen3, 6 Gbps
Temperature  : 41 °C
Highest Temp.: 49 °C
Health       : 100 %
Performance  : 100 %
Power on time: 48 days, 17 hours
Est. lifetime: more than 1000 days
  The hard disk status is PERFECT. Problematic or weak sectors were not found and there are no spin up or data transfer errors. 
    No actions needed.

The results of long test from smartctl
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.10.1-arch1-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5 (SMR)
Device Model:     ST2000DM008-2UB102
Serial Number:    WK30LBZ6
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0f1a9797e
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jul 27 04:21:20 2024 +03
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 200) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30a5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   080   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       91635948
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       692
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   082   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       142332177
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1180h+17m+12.848s
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       692
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 3
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   058   051   040    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 42/43)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       406
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1444
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   042   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (0 18 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   080   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       91635948
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1144h+28m+33.866s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6730140016
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1535526694

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1180         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1169         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

The above only provides legacy SMART information - try 'smartctl -x' for more


There are some errors on dmesg, but I don't know what to make out of the errors.
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:06 2024] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:06 2024] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:06 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:06 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:48:98:11:04/00:00:0a:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:06 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:06 2024] ata3: hard resetting link
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:11 2024] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:13 2024] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:13 2024] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:13 2024] ata3: EH complete
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x11c000 SErr 0x40d0202 action 0xe frozen
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/18:70:08:2b:c0/00:00:46:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 12288 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:78:20:2b:c0/00:00:46:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/e0:80:28:2b:c0/00:00:46:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 114688 in
                                    res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: cmd 61/28:a0:a8:6b:54/00:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 20480 out
                                    res 40/00:ff:ff:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:30 2024] ata3: hard resetting link
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:33 2024] retire_capture_urb: 1 callbacks suppressed
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:36 2024] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 46 c0 2b 08 00 00 18 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1186999048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 3
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 46 c0 2b 28 00 00 e0 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1186999080 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 28 prio class 3
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:38 2024] ata3: EH complete
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:42 2024] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x80 SErr 0x40d0202 action 0xe frozen
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:42 2024] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:42 2024] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:42 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:42 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:38:d0:47:21/00:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:42 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:42 2024] ata3: hard resetting link
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:47 2024] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:49 2024] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:49 2024] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
[Fri Jul 26 14:45:49 2024] ata3: EH complete
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:03 2024] retire_capture_urb: 10 callbacks suppressed
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: limiting speed to UDMA/33:PIO4
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x40000200 SErr 0x40d0202 action 0xe frozen
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:48:20:a4:c7/00:00:27:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:f0:18:aa:44/00:00:3e:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:17 2024] ata3: hard resetting link
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:23 2024] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 27 c7 a4 20 00 00 08 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 667395104 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3e 44 aa 18 00 00 08 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1044687384 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:24 2024] ata3: EH complete
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:30 2024] retire_capture_urb: 3 callbacks suppressed
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:35 2024] retire_capture_urb: 12 callbacks suppressed
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x39bf0 SErr 0x40d0202 action 0xe frozen
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:20:00:c6:50/00:00:40:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:28:00:4c:50/00:00:40:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:30:78:cb:44/00:00:0f:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:38:00:0b:50/00:00:40:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:40:00:4a:50/00:00:40:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:48:00:15:2c/00:00:0e:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:58:00:08:50/00:00:40:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/20:60:00:34:51/00:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 16384 in
                                    res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/40:78:20:a6:51/00:00:40:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 32768 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:80:60:a6:51/00:00:40:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 65536 in
                                    res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: cmd 61/08:88:40:55:45/00:00:41:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 4096 out
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:50 2024] ata3: hard resetting link
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:56 2024] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:57 2024] retire_capture_urb: 3 callbacks suppressed
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 40 50 c6 00 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1079035392 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 40 50 4c 00 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1079004160 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0f 44 cb 78 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 256166776 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 40 50 0b 00 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1078987520 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 40 50 4a 00 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1079003648 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0e 2c 15 00 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 237769984 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 40 50 08 00 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1078986752 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=9s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0c 51 34 00 00 00 20 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 206648320 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=8s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 40 51 a6 20 00 00 40 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1079092768 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=8s
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 40 51 a6 60 00 00 80 00
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1079092832 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
[Fri Jul 26 14:46:59 2024] ata3: EH complete
[Fri Jul 26 14:47:15 2024] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x20000 SErr 0x40d0202 action 0xe frozen
[Fri Jul 26 14:47:15 2024] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[Fri Jul 26 14:47:15 2024] ata3: SError: { RecovComm Persist PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[Fri Jul 26 14:47:15 2024] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Jul 26 14:47:15 2024] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:88:00:f9:80/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 4096 in
                                    res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Jul 26 14:47:15 2024] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }

What should I search for? Are there any other logs that these types of error logged in?
I have a second PC, but don't have any other PCs that I can plug this HDD into. I have external HDD boxes though.

Your disk is starting to fail, or the controller thinks it's dropping offline. Backup your data, replace the disk.

run sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdb. Post sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb results when it finishes (will take at least 4 hours).

·@waltinator I was thinking the same, but it's only 3 or 4 months old. Maybe it was faulty out of the factory.
@ArtemS.Tashkinov started the test, will post results when it finishes
